# Script to simulate "enter" keypress on a pop-up window using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, keypress, tampermonkey

I do not have much scripting knowledge.

I am looking for a Tampermonkey script to do this:

I will be working on a web page that times out after 10 minutes of inactivity. And it will open a small pop-up window that has the URL as "about:blank", I'm guessing it works with Javascript as the main web page works on it. This pop-up window will have an "OK" button (code below) that will keep my session active if I press that button. Pressing "Enter" on keyboard also works. So, I am looking for a tampermonkey script to simulate the "Enter" button keypress whenever this pop-up window opens.

Code of the pop-up window:

```
<html><head>
<title>Session Timeout Warning. - 8:03:15 AM</title>
<script language="javascript">
function reactivateSession() {
var theUrl = window.location.pathname + '?';
theUrl += '&ETQ$CMD=CMD_REACTIVATE_SESSION';
document.forms[0].target = '_self';
document.forms[0].method = 'post';
document.forms[0].action = theUrl;
document.forms[0].submit();
}</script>
</head>
<body style="color:#000000; font-size:12px; font-family: sans-serif; padding-top:3px;background-color:#A8B8C8"><form><b><center>
Your session is about to time out.</center><br><center>Warning: Session time out will result in the loss of unsaved data.</center></b>
<br><br><center>
<input id="OkButton" type="button" style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial;FONT-SIZE: 8pt;FONT-WEIGHT: normal;vertical-align: top; width: 80px" name="OK" value="OK" onclick="reactivateSession();this.value='Please wait ...';this.disabled=true">
</center></form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you considered simulating mouse events on a page instead? Have look on the code that detects inactivity and try to tamper with that.

Comment: @TomášZato No, I didn't try anything, can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events